# how to optimize code using factory pattern?

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

i have the following code with to connect ot wifi based on diffrent types of authentication type

```
private const string ccmp = "CCMP";
    private const string wpa = "WPA_PSK";
    private const string tkip = "TKIP";


 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                {

                    if (encryption == ccmp)
                    {
                        if (authenticationType == wpa)
                        {
                            var profile = string.Format(Constants.WPAPSK_PROFILE, profileName, ssidHex, password);
                            ConnectToWifi(profileName, wlanIface, profile);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var profile = string.Format(Constants.WPA2_PROFILE, profileName, ssidHex, password);
                            ConnectToWifi(profileName, wlanIface, profile);
                        }
                    }

                    else if (encryption == tkip)
                    {
                        if (authenticationType == wpa)
                        {

                            var profile = string.Format(Constants.TKIPWPA_PROFILE, profileName, ssidHex, password);
                            ConnectToWifi(profileName, wlanIface, profile);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            var profile = string.Format(Constants.TKIPWPA2_PROFILE, profileName, ssidHex, password);
                            ConnectToWifi(profileName, wlanIface, profile);
                        }
                    }


                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var existingProfile = wlanIface.GetProfileXml(profileName);
                            if (existingProfile != null)
                            {
                                wlanIface.DeleteProfile(profileName);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            var ex = e;
                        }
                        var profile = string.Format(Constants.WEP_PROFILE, profileName, ssidHex, password);
                        ConnectToWifi(profileName, wlanIface, profile);

                    }
                }



   private void ConnectToWifi(string profileName, WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface, string profile)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {

            try
            {
                wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profile, true);
                wlanIface.ConnectSynchronously(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Infrastructure, profileName, 5000);
                SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => Networking.IsNetworkConnected(), 5000);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var ex = e;
            }
            finally
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { CheckStatus(); }));
            }

        }).Start();
    }
```

it clearly in working mode, But the code seems to be little lengthy and complex.
How can i optimize the code using Factory pattern?

Comment: If the code actually works then this question looks like it would be a better fit for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: pure factory is for creation always the same initial data set. When options are changeable (like here) read about builder pattern. BTW builder is kind of factory with higher logic